# Using highcharts with a dojo front-end

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, dojo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct'
        ], function (dom, domConstruct) {
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
            domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
        });
    </script>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, {
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 7, 3]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how I can integrate highcharts into a dojo front end? The error message I receive with this code is...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> dojo.html:24:27
```

Eventually I will have to get this working for the ESRI web app builder which is built on dojo so I am hoping the dojo versions are the same. Would somebody let me know how to check that as well? I know an adaptor was made for this in 2014 (https://github.com/ben8p/highcharts.com-dojo-adapter) however I could not find documentation on how to use it and the owner of this repo was unable to offer further assistance as they have not worked on this project for some time.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using dojo with Highcharts is not officially supported. It seems to work with Highcharts 5, but It is always recommended to use the latest version.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wy3mu4pt/

Dojo adapter for highcharts is one of our community wrappers. As I noticed in the github project it is tested with Highcharts 3.0.7 version, so it might not be compatible with our latest highcharts version as well. The only possibility to get the answers to the specific dojo adapter's questions is to contact the author.